# Ruby: Selenium: Webpage has strange page behavior for list, want to loop through each link in list

Tags: ruby, loops, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I have the following code:

```
list = [#array of xpaths pointing to each of the 41 links]
begin
    list.each do |entry|
        wait.until {browser.find_element(xpath: entry)}
        browser.find_element(xpath: entry).click
        ... #do what needs to be done inside link
        browser.find_element(xpath: #location of back button) #goes back to list
    end
    wait.until{browser.find_element(css: ".next>a")}
    browser.find_element(css: ".next>a").click 
    # ^ clicks the next button to get to next page
    sleep 2
end while browser.find_element(class_name: "next").displayed?
# ^ end when there is no next button because were on the last page.
```

I am looping through each link on the page, doing what I need to do with it, and returning to the list. When all 41 links have been hit on the page, I tell it to load the next page. The issue is that for some reason going back to the list always goes back to the first page. So if I am on the third page and I click the link, do what I have to do, and return to the list I am back on the first page of the list. Anyone have an ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: Reduce your code to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem you're asking. Anything beyond that wastes our time as we try to help you.

Comment: Okay edited the code to make it clearer.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between page & links here.  You're looping through links yet your expecting to be looping through pages?

Comment: There's two loops the .each loop runs until all the links ( from the array) are passed then the next button is hit to get the the next page of links. Its should then run the each loop again but now on page 2. The problem is when the code should go back to page 2 to find the next link it is sent back to page 1. So I need to find a way to get back to the correct page before moving to the next link.

Comment: I think the solution would be dependent on how the web page is implemented. Please consider sharing a page or html that reproduces the behviour you see.